# New message notification in list view of users in android chat application

Tags: android, parsing

Hi I am developing an android chat application using parse as back end and sinch service.
Everything is working fine like sending and receiving messages between two android devices.I am also using push notification from parse.com.
Now i want to modify the applications like when the new message arrives it must show that the message is pending in my chat application same as that
Whats-App

Here is my code

**ListUserActivity.java**

```
    private void setConversationsList() {
    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUserId);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, com.parse.ParseException    e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                    names.add(userList.get(i).getUsername().toString());
                }
                usersListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
                namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i,   long l) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(i);
                            openConversation(names, i);
                        }
                        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e1){
                            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
  }
```

**MessagingActivity.java**

```
public class MessagingActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private String recipientId;
private String name;
private EditText messageBodyField;
private String messageBody;
private MessageService.MessageServiceInterface messageService;
private MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
private ListView messagesList;
private String currentUserId;
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new MyServiceConnection();
private MessageClientListener messageClientListener = new MyMessageClientListener();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.messaging);

    bindService(new Intent(this, MessageService.class), serviceConnection,   BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    recipientId = intent.getStringExtra("RECIPIENT_ID");
    name=intent.getStringExtra("name");
    setTitle(name);
    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();

    // Store app language and version
    ParseInstallation installation =   ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    installation.put("userI", currentUserId);
    installation.saveInBackground();

    messagesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
    messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this);
    messagesList.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
    populateMessageHistory();

    messageBodyField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageBodyField);

    findViewById(R.id.sendButton).setOnClickListener(new   View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });
}

//get previous messages from parse & display
private void populateMessageHistory() {
    String[] userIds = {currentUserId, recipientId};
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ParseMessage") ;
    query.whereContainedIn("senderId", Arrays.asList(userIds));
    query.whereContainedIn("recipientId", Arrays.asList(userIds));
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> messageList,   com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < messageList.size(); i++) {
                    WritableMessage message = new    WritableMessage(messageList.get(i).get("recipientId").toString(),  messageList.get(i).get("messageText").toString());
                    if  (messageList.get(i).get("senderId").toString().equals(currentUserId)) {
                        messageAdapter.addMessage(message,   MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_OUTGOING);
                    } else {
                        messageAdapter.addMessage(message,  MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_INCOMING);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void sendMessage() {
    messageBody = messageBodyField.getText().toString();
    if (messageBody.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    messageService.sendMessage(recipientId, messageBody);
    messageBodyField.setText("");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    messageService.removeMessageClientListener(messageClientListener);
    unbindService(serviceConnection);
    super.onDestroy();
}

private class MyServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        messageService = (MessageService.MessageServiceInterface) iBinder;
        messageService.addMessageClientListener(messageClientListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        messageService = null;
    }
}
private class MyMessageClientListener implements MessageClientListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessageFailed(MessageClient client, Message message,
                                MessageFailureInfo failureInfo) {
        Toast.makeText(MessagingActivity.this, "Message failed to send.",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onIncomingMessage(MessageClient client, Message message) {
        if (message.getSenderId().equals(recipientId)) {
           //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            WritableMessage writableMessage = new WritableMessage(message.getRecipientIds().get(0), message.getTextBody());
            messageAdapter.addMessage(writableMessage,  MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_INCOMING);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageSent(MessageClient client, Message message, final String recipientId) {

        final WritableMessage writableMessage = new WritableMessage(message.getRecipientIds().get(0), message.getTextBody());
        messageAdapter.addMessage(writableMessage, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_OUTGOING);
        //only add message to parse database if it doesn't already exist there
       ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ParseMessage");
        query.whereEqualTo("sinchId", message.getMessageId());
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> messageList, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

                    if (messageList.size() == 0) {
                        ParseObject parseMessage = new ParseObject("ParseMessage");
                        parseMessage.put("senderId", currentUserId);
                        parseMessage.put("recipientId", writableMessage.getRecipientIds().get(0));
                        parseMessage.put("messageText", writableMessage.getTextBody());
                        parseMessage.put("sinchId", writableMessage.getMessageId());
                        parseMessage.put("read",false);
                        parseMessage.saveInBackground();
                        //  messageAdapter.addMessage(writableMessage, MessageAdapter.DIRECTION_OUTGOING);

                        ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                        String name = user.getUsername();
                       // Create our Installation query
                        ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
                        pushQuery.whereEqualTo("userI", writableMessage.getRecipientIds().get(0));

                        // Send push notification to query
                        ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
                        push.setQuery(pushQuery); // Set our Installation query
                        push.setMessage("Message from"+ name +writableMessage.getTextBody());
                        push.sendInBackground();

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageDelivered(MessageClient client, MessageDeliveryInfo deliveryInfo) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"delivered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onShouldSendPushData(MessageClient client, Message message,    List<PushPair> pushPairs) {}
}
```

}

Comment: When you say pending, do you mean you want a notification on starus bar? Or you want the conversation highlighted on your list?

Comment: I want the conversation highlighted on users list view where all user''s are listed thank you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new column to your database that keeps track if the conversation has unread messages. Whenever a new message arrives you mark the conversation as unread or pending by setting this column to true. 
When you build the list, make your adapter check this column and update the generated listview if the conversation has unread messages.
When the user opens the conversation, update the column to false.

First I suggest you use a ListView with a CursorLoader:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Whenever your content provider changes, your adapter will be notified. When it is looping through the cursor building each list item View, you check the desired column. If it is set, you set whatever you like on that View to indicate it is unread.

Comment: please help me with this by referring any articles where building list adapter and checking the columns and updating listview

Comment: I added more information. But you have to decide what will be different on list items that have unread messages. This is particular to your app.